# Winsorize by factors in R?

Tags: r

I am having trouble figuring out how to winsorize by group and condition for my data. In the past I have created new vectors for each group and condition, winsorized separately, and then bound the vectors back together. This seems inefficient and I am now working with a larger data set that would make that process time consuming. I have tried using dplyr, but have not had luck. Here is an example of my data and what I am trying to do.

```
library(robustHD)
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(id = rep(1:10, each=3),
                 group = rep(c('group1', 'group2'), each =3),
                 condition = rep(c('cond1', 'cond2', 'cond3'), times = 10),
                 measure = rep(1:5, each=3) + rnorm(15))

df$measure.win <- df %>% group_by(group, condition) %>%
  winsorize(df, measure)
```

This is the error I keep getting:

```
Error in FUN(x, aperm(array(STATS, dims[perm]), order(perm)), ...) : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please specify all the `library()`es you are using that are not included in base R?

Comment: is winsorize your own function? if so you would need to share the code for that.
the error usually means your trying to do a mathematical operation on non-numeric data.

Comment: To add to jay.sf's comment: we can't be sure which package you are using for the "winsorize" function. (There is more than one package that includes this function.)

Comment: @jay.sf I have updated with the package used for winsorize. Sorry about that!

Comment: Hi @adneuro3, I don't see the package information in your post. Is it possible that you forgot to save the revised post?

Comment: @user2363777 hello, sorry yes it did not save for some reason. Should be updated now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

`df = df %>% 
  group_by(group, condition) %>%
  mutate(measure_winsorized = winsorize(measure))`

(If you're interested in a dplyr tutorial, I highly recommend [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/dplyr.html) one.)

**Initial response:**

In general, using the `%>%` will provide the output of the function preceding the pipe as input to the function following the pipe. So if you would call the `winsorize()` function by itself using `winsorize(df, measure)`, you should leave out the first argument and use `winsorize(measure)` here, because the output of the preceding `group_by(group_condition)` is a dataframe.

In other words: what may be happening here is that your function call is interpreted as `winsorize(df, df, measure)`.

If you could share which package your `winsorize()` function is in, I can help you come up with the appropriate dplyr code.

Comment: Hi @user2363777, I have updated my post with the package being used for winsorize. Sorry about that!

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem! If this resolves your question, please mark my answer as accepted. (You can click on the check mark besides the answer to fill it in.)